# Doing a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to do a loop (which I haven't done before) and given the observations (column 1), I need to work out (i) which of the combinations across the variables (s1-s5) are significant (P<0.05), (ii) to only keep the combinations that are significant across the variables with the corresponding p values. I thought that this would be a good way to learn how to do a loop in R. The original data is large and is similar to this one:

```
ob <- c(120,100,85,56,87)
s1 <- c("ab","aa","ab","aa","bb")
s2 <- c("aa","aa","ab","bb","bb")
s3 <- c("bb","ab","aa","ab","ab")
s4 <- c("aa","ab","bb","ab","aa")
s5 <- c("bb","ab","aa","ab","bb")
dset <- data.frame(ob,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
```

dset

```
ob s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
120 ab aa bb aa bb
100 aa aa ab ab ab
85 ab ab aa bb aa
56 aa bb ab ab ab
87 bb bb ab aa bb
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Baz

Comment: how do you determine significance? How do the columns s1 - s5 play into the significance? There is almost certainly a vectorized solution that will not need to use a for-loop here, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @Chase, the significance level would be P<0.05 and s1-s5 are sets of snips which are thought to have influenced the performance of cattle in the herd.

Comment: so now you want to run a linear regression for all combinations of s1 thru s5? Is that right?

Comment: @Chase, yes, for each observation. i believe you are right!

Comment: The contents of your question have changed fairly substantially. I think this has type of approach has been addressed well on cross validated. See @gd047's answer for how to create an exhaustive list of all the combinations of your independent variables. Then you can modify the sapply code to extract the p-values, or whatever other statistics you need: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/aggregating-results-from-linear-model-runs-r

Comment: Statistical appropriateness aside, you may also find the stepAIC function from MASS or leaps from leaps helpful in identifying the best model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing how it makes sense to add a column of p-values in your data.frame without transposing the data.frame. How do you know which p-value corresponds to which independent variable if they are in different columns? Here's one approach using a for-loop to run the anova's for each independent variable and store them on a new vector:

```
#Use grep to return the columns that match the pattern "s". This returns their column index. 
#This is what we'll use in the for loop
vars <- grep("s", names(dset))

#Create a new vector to hold the anova results and name it
dat <- vector("integer", length = ncol(dset))
names(dat) <- colnames(dset)

#Run for loop, assigning the p-value from the anova to the proper spot in the vector we made
for (var in vars) {
  dat[var] <- anova(lm(ob ~ dset[, var], data = dset))$"Pr(>F)"[1]
}
```

All of the above will yield:

```
> dat
       ob        s1        s2        s3        s4        s5 
0.0000000 0.7219532 0.3108441 0.4668372 0.6908916 0.6908916
```

I'll leave it up to you as to how you want to relate that back to the original data.frame.

Comment: yes you are right! the question was confusing and I do apologise for that. I have just edited it and hope that it is now making sense, i hope!